# CiviMail : SPF REcord/SPAM issue

Tags: civimail, spam, failure

I am trying to configure/use civimail. When I send an email from CivCRM, it goes directly to the spam foler of the recipent. Looking at the mail header, I see
Received-SPF: Fail (protection.outlook.com: domain of hamap.org does not
designate 212.129.46.140 as permitted sender).
Looking at CiviCRM documentation, I understand thar I need to create a SPF record using openSPF but OpenSPF does not exist anymore. Can someone tell me how to create a SPF record or something similar? Thks.

Configuring Sender Policy Framework (SPF)

By default, the Internet allows any mail server to send any email claiming to be from anyone. This makes it easy for spammers to forge addresses and send spam using your email address (or any other). SPF allows you to create a special DNS record listing the IP addresses of the mail servers that can legitimately send email from @yourdomain.org.

If your domain name already has an SPF record, make sure that it includes the IP address of your CiviCRM mail server (which might be a different from the host used for the web server or from your mail servers), and if it doesn't, add this IP address.

If you don't have an SPF record, consider adding one. You will need to add at least your mail server and CiviCRM server (if they are different) to the SPF record.

You can read more about SPF at http://www.openspf.org.

Comment: Have you checked out https://mxtoolbox.com/spf.aspx to confirm you're setings etc? This will help with the amendments you need to make.

Answer (score 0):

You don't set up the SPF record at [www.openspf.org](http://www.openspf.org). That was just a link for more information in the docs and it looks like it no longer exists. I'd start with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework to understand what its about but you can also google a range of other resources around on setting up email that would be useful. There is also DMARC and DKIM and the whole lot is quite complicated, but necessary to make sure all your email gets delivered.

Its also worth trying to email to other domains as not all of them require senders to have SPF records, to see that everything else is working. What you need to do will depend on what method you are using to deliver the mail so there are quite a few variations - you need to ensure the right IP address is included in the SPF record.

Comment: Just spotted that the link in the documentation was just wrong and should be http://www.open-spf.org , but the site hasn't been updated in years.